# Proper way to redeclare function in own module

Tags: hooks

Using module [isotope](https://www.drupal.org/project/isotope) for drupal 7, I would like to redeclare/overwrite the function `theme_isotope_filter(array $vars)` which is in file isotope.module. But what is the proper name to overwrite it? My custom modules name is `my_module`, so I tried to overwrite it ineptly by naming it `my_module_theme_isotope_filter(array $vars)` or `theme_my_module_filter(array $vars)`. I also tried to implement it as `mythemename_isotope_filter(array $vars)` in template.php. But nothing worked. Do I have to overwrite the function in my custom module or in template.php? And what is the proper name to do so?

Comment: `my_module_isotop_filter(array $vars)` should work, or `mythemename_isotope_filter(array $vars)` should have also worked. Did you cleared the caches?

Comment: yes, i cleared the caches multile times.

Comment: mythemename_isotope_filter works! but only when I use it in my custom module, not in template.php! thanks!